# How do the finite partitioning principle compare with infinite Dedekindian addition?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, cardinal-characteristics

In a posting to [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509537/is-the-finite-partitioning-principle-equivalent-to-a-form-of-choice), what I've labeld as the **finite partitioning principle** was [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4509611/489784) to be implied by the principle that for every infinite set $X$, $X+X=X$, what I'd label as the **Infinite Dedekindian Addition principle**.

To quote the first principle:

> By the finite partitioning principle I mean the following: Every infinite set is the union of pairwise disjoint finite sets all larger than 1 in cardinality. In other words every infinite set can be partitioned into a family of non-singleton finite compartments.  Formally: $$\forall \operatorname {infinite} X , \exists Y: \\\forall a,b \in Y (a \cap b =\emptyset \land 1 < |a| < \aleph_0) \land X=\bigcup Y$$

What I want to ask here is:

> What is the actual comparison between those two principles, is the finite partitioning principle strictly weaker than the Infinite Dedekindian addition principle? Or they are equivalent?